# Using selenium, not able to open Firefox with a saved profile

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I have created a new Firefox profile, and want to call the profile in my selenium code to load Firefox using this profile (plugins, etc).

Given the code below.

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Software\\Firefox\\Driver\\geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe"); 

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("C:\\Users\\Dev 8\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\j3yl2vj7.MyTest02"));                  

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

It opens Firefox with the default settings, instead of with my particular profile with the plugins etc.

Version information:

- Selenium : selenium-java-3.0.0-beta2
- Java     : Java SE 1.7
- Firefox  : 45.0.2

Comment: I have edited your question to rephrase some of the sentence for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2016/07/29/announcing-selenium-3-0-beta1/) blog article, you need to run Selenium 3.0 with Java 8.